# Should I upload css + maps to the server? And does it slow down the website?

Tags: sass

I have two issues that need support, whether to upload the scss file, and the map file to the server after the job has finished? And does it increase page load time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally use a build system (gulp) and a repo for maintaining sites. I don't include the .css files, those are all .gitignored to prevent conflicts. So when an update is pushed live, I just pull it down, and run a gulp task to build the .css file and maps. So I end up having both the sass, and the map file on the production server.

Having the sass file doesn't affect load time. The browser doesn't actually load that, it will load your .css sheet. The map files do increase the load time though, as they are being called, but its extremely minimal. You're looking at maybe 150kb and 70ms depending on the size of the css which directly effects the size of the map.

I wouldn't worry about it, but it's up to you how important that 70ms is.